# How to replace line with file contents and around the content with some text?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I would like to combine VPN certificates into a single file. This is a template file:

```
# some unrelated stuff 

ca ca.crt

# other unrelated stuff
```

And I want to replace line `ca ca.crt` with the following content:

```
<ca>
# ca.crt contents
</ca>
```

I tried this script:

```
cat client-template.ovpn | 
sed -e 's/ca ca.crt/<ca>\n<\/ca>/' | 
sed -e '/<ca>/r ca.crt'
```

Although this script works fine, I have to paste two other files along with `ca.crt`, and I would like to know, is there any command, which allows to combine both `s` and `r` commands together?

I am using `sed`, but answers with other Unix tools are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

With good old `ed`:

```
ed -s client-template.ovpn <<\IN
/ca ca.crt/s//<ca>\
<\/ca>/
- r ca.crt
/cert client.crt/s//<cert>\
<\/cert>/
- r client.crt
/key client.key/s//<key>\
<\/key>/
- r client.key
,p
q
IN
```

this changes a line like

```
tag tag.extension
```

to

```
<tag>
</tag>
```

and then `r`eads in the content of `tag.extension` before (`-`) the closing tag line (i.e. the current line after the substitution). Replace `,p` with `w` to actually write the changes to your template file (or use `w somefile` to save changes to another file). Keep in mind though that `ed` will error out if a pattern is not found.

With `sed` you could combine `r` with `a` (`a`, like `r`, does not operate on pattern space - unlike `s` which does):

```
sed '
/ca ca.crt/{
s//<ca>/
r ca.crt
a\
</ca>
}
/cert client.crt/{
s//<cert>/
r client.crt
a\
</cert>
}
/key client.key/{
s//<key>/
r client.key
a\
</key>
}
' client-template.ovpn
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `sed`, assuming those ca file name don't contain single quote characters, you could do:

```
sed "s|^ca \(.*\)|echo '<ca>'; cat '\1'; echo '</ca>'|e"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/ca cert.crt/<ca>/' -e 'T' -e 'r cert.crt' -e 'a\</ca>' client-template.ovpn
```

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately, this script replaces `ca cert.crt` with `<ca> \n ca cert.crt \n</ca> \n *file content*`. I want to place the content inside `<ca>` tag. I also have a type in the question: not `ca cert.crt` but `ca ca.crt`. Could you, please, fix this in your answer in order to make posts more consistent?

Comment: @soon See edited

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I would not use sed, but use the approach mentioned in this thread - https://serverfault.com/questions/287688/templating-with-linux-in-a-shell-script

The idea is to use bash itself as the templating language, so you can easily do things like include files in your template.

Your template thus becomes a bash script that you run to generate your file. Applying it to your problem might look something like this:

make-client.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<-EOF
# some unrelated stuff

<ca>
$(cat ca.crt)
</ca>

<other>
$(cat other.file)
</other>

# other unrelated stuff
EOF
```

Usage from command-line:

```
$ make-client.sh > client.ovpn
```

Comment: I thought about this approach, however, I wouldn't like to modify the template config. It was generated by OpenVPN and I would like to take it *as is*. Thank you for the answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems to be possible using a combination of `r` and `D` e.g.

```
sed '/^ca ca.crt/ {
r new-content-file
D
}' client-template.ovpn
```

Comment: Not exactly so. `ca ca.crt` should be replaced with `<ca> *here the ca.crt content* </ca>`. I could achieve this using two commands, as I noted at the end of the question, however, I am looking for a single command, since writing similar code for three files (I have to paste `ca.crt`, `client.crt` and `client.key` contents into `<ca>`, `<cert>` and `<key>` respectively) seems graceless for me.

Comment: @soon sorry - I still don't see the distinction. Perhaps you should edit your question to include the additional requirement(s) more clearly i.e. examples of all 3 files and the **full** desired output. Is it simply a matter of adding a further two `r` commands?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to support a variable file name after the word `ca`. While [you can do it with GNU sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230920), I'd use awk (or Perl).

```
awk '
    $1 == "ca" && NR == 2 { # if the current line consists of two words, the first of which is "ca"
        print "<ca>";
        while (getline <$2) print;
        close($2);
        print "</ca>";
    }
    1    # print anything else unmodified
'client-template.ovpn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '5 i\
<ca>
     5 r tempo.csv
     5 a\
</ca>
     5 d' client-template.ovpn
```

- order of action is important (especially the `d` as last action
- new line is represented by a ending `\` in `i`nsert and `a`ppend action

Comment: Not sure, if I understand your answer correctly, but will it paste the content of `ca.crt` file to the `client-template.ovpn`?

Comment: adapted the reply for a generic file and surrounding value